# Parse listview only loads the first 99 items of the class, instead of all of them

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I've followed the tutorial (http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/) and build up my apps successfully. But I've got a problem. There are more than 100 items in my parse class, but the app listview only loads and show the first 99 items. How can I load all the 100+ items in the app?

Comment: I think you have to set the limit of the the PFQuery. I maybe wrong but I think that parse limits a request automatically to 100 items unless manually changed

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned @Paulo [query limited by default to 100 results](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/). 
So if you want to get more call the method `setLimit()` on your query object. Also worth to mention that you can't get more than 1000 at a time anyway due to Parse restrictions